# I changed the SMTP and SMTP Port but it still says Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25

Tags: php, sendmail

I am currently using `xampp 1.7.0` and my php version is `5.2.8`

I changed my `php.ini` file to:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
```

and my send_email.php file looks like:

```
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a test message.";
$from = "someonelse@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

But, it shows the following message:

`Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\NFL\send_email.php on line 15`

Line number 15 is:

`mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);`

How can I resolve this issue?

Note: I also added a 5th parameter to the mail call to force the system to use the From Email Address, but it didn't worked!

Comment: have you restart your apache server? restart it.

Comment: do a phpinfo() inside your script to verify that the settings in effect are the ones you've set. Sometimes there are multiple php.ini files, you may be changing the wrong one (phpinfo will also tell you the location to the loaded php.ini file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution to my own question. The problem was:

At first I was changing the `php.ini` file from `C:\xampp\php\`

But, when I did

```
 echo phpinfo();
 die();
```

I found the `loaded configuration file` was:

```
C:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
```

So, I changed

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

to

```
SMTP = smtp.wlink.com.np
smtp_port = 25
```

And it worked!

Comment: Failed to connect to mailserver at smtp.wlink.com.np port 25, verify your SMTP and smtp_port setting in php.ini.